# Question of Fourier Transform calculation

Tags: fourier-transform

If we do Fourier Transform of $~1~$ then the equation will be
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-j w t}~dt$$

then how can I figure out $~e^{j∞}~$ or $~e^{-j∞}~$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Is it ok ? @Dongenu Shin.           I think there are something wrong.

Comment: $1$ only has a fourier transform in a more generalised sense (in the sense of distributions)

Comment: i want to know the process of calculating FT of 1 // in the FT table i know Ft of 1 is 2pi*impluse function(w)